# Multiply the number of rows based on a specified range

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working on an automation task in python wherein there should be an input to specify the start range and end range ..and based on those numbers the dataframe should mutiply

```
Name 
Harish
Ed
```

> Specify the start : 34

> > specify the end : 38

```
Name     Range
Harish   34
Harish   35
Harish   36
Harish   37
Ed       34
Ed       35
Ed       36
Ed       37
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with `matplotlib`, please don't spam tags

Answer (score 0):

Use cross join with helper `DataFrame`:

```
s = 34
e = 38
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':1, 'Range': range(s, e)})
df = df.assign(a=1).merge(df1, on='a').drop('a', axis=1)
print (df)
     Name  Range
0  Harish     34
1  Harish     35
2  Harish     36
3  Harish     37
4      Ed     34
5      Ed     35
6      Ed     36
7      Ed     37
```

If working only  with one column:

```
s = 34
e = 38

from  itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame(product(df['Name'], range(s, e)), columns=['Name','Range'])
print (df1)
     Name  Range
0  Harish     34
1  Harish     35
2  Harish     36
3  Harish     37
4      Ed     34
5      Ed     35
6      Ed     36
7      Ed     37
```